# Making changes to debug Python script results in error returned for syntax issue

Tags: python, unix, aws-cli

I have a script I found here:

https://n2ws.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/ebs-report.py

Running it returns the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ebs-report.py", line 194, in <module>
    retval = create_ebs_report (args.regions, args.access_key, args.secret_key, args.file)
  File "ebs-report.py", line 130, in create_ebs_report
    'type' : volume_types_map[vol.type],
KeyError: u'st1'
```

There is no mapping for st1 (which is a type of volume from aws that perhaps didn't exist when the script was written) so I am trying to resolve this.

I am hoping that the error can be resolved by adding that extra volume type so change the script here:

```
volume_types_map = { u'standard' : u'Standard/Magnetic', u'io1' : u'Provisioned IOPS (SSD)', u'gp2' : u'General Purpose SSD'}
```

To this...

```
volume_types_map = { u'standard' : u'Standard/Magnetic', u'io1' : u'Provisioned IOPS (SSD)', u'gp2' : u'General Purpose SSD', u'Throughput Optimized HDD', u'st1'}
```

So basically I am adding the st1 part on to the mapping in the hope that it sorts out the issue.

This results in an error. I must have got the syntax wrong within the extra value that I added to the "volume_types_map"...

```
File "ebs-report2.py", line 102
    volume_types_map = { u'standard' : u'Standard/Magnetic', u'io1' : u'Provisioned IOPS (SSD)', u'gp2' : u'General Purpose SSD', u'Throughput Optimized HDD', u'st1'}
                                                                                                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the error that results from my change, above.

Can anyone help with what I seem to have incorrectly added and identify where I may have gone wrong, I suspect with the commas colons and spaces.

Comment: "so change the script here" The part you added doesn't follow the pattern of the existing data. Pay closer attention. `'st1'` is the key you want to look up; does the existing data put the keys first or second? What symbol does the existing data put between the key and the corresponding value?

Comment: Thanks - I have swapped out the comma for a colon and I am back to an issue with the key. I do not really understand the relationship between the u and the text in single quotes and the commas either. Do all of these values have to correspond to what they are searching for within aws? -- This is the new error...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ebs-report2.py", line 194, in <module>
    retval = create_ebs_report (args.regions, args.access_key, args.secret_key, args.file)
  File "ebs-report2.py", line 130, in create_ebs_report
    'type' : volume_types_map[vol.type],
KeyError: u'st1'

Answer (score 1):

You should add the st1 (Throughput Optimized) type to the script so it gets recognized

```
            volume_types_map = {u'standard': u'Standard/Magnetic', u'io1': 
            u'Provisioned IOPS (SSD)', u'gp2': u'General Purpose SSD', u'st1': 
            u'Throughput Optimized HDD'}
```